# Laravel 8 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I don't know what's wrong because I'm very new to this.

```
// Product Model
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }
}
```

```
// Store Model
class Store extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```
// Products table migration
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->float('price');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreignId('store_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

```
// Stores table migration
Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('image_url');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I run the migration, it gives me this error
[image: The error]

I've tried changing the data type of the 'id' but still not working. I've also tried with

```
$table->foreign('store_id')->references('id')->on('stores')->onDelete('cascade');
```

but still not working.

What I want is a relation so that when I delete a store, all products that belong the store are also deleted.

Thanks

Comment: Your migration order is wrong. your product existance depends on the stores (foreign key) but it's migrated before the stores. hence the error. Change the date of the stores migration file and set it before the one of the products (2021_07_28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the stores migration file to a date prior to 2021-07-28 so the table `stores` is migrated before the table `products`

Example: `2021_07_27_004700_create_stores_table`

Laravel uses the name of the migration files for the order of migration. With the format of the date as the start of the file name, it is dependant on the date of the creation of the file.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it worked! I didn't know that the order of migration matters.