# Laravel 9 foreignId [Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed]

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am getting an error while using foreign keys.

##### Products migration

```php
Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id(); // Ürün adı
    $table->string('name'); //Ürün adı
    //$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('category');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### Category migration

```php
Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('main_category')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('commission');
});
```

##### Error

> General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`product` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I'am using laravel 9

Comment: is your category migration launched before the product migration ? what is the name of the migration files ?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562276/laravel-8-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed/68562415#68562415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the order in which you created the migrations but the categories table will need to exist before you create the product table.